# Комплектуючі, комплектувальні чи комплектовання?

Tags: вибір-слова, дієприкметники

[Словопедія](http://slovopedia.org.ua/28/53402/3613.html) дає опозицію **комплектуючі** - **комплектувальні**, пояснення нема.

Наприклад, у контекстах, майж однакових за смислом, вжито різні форми слова:

- комплектуючі тут https://ventilator.ua/ua/category/komplektujushie-sistem-ventiljacii/
- а тут комплектувальні https://zakupki.prom.ua/gov/tenders/UA-2017-12-19-003136-c

Активні дієприкметники небажані, тож що правильно вживати - субстантив **комплектувальні** чи, може, іменик **комплектовання**?

Answer (score 1):

Якщо *[паковання](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F&scope=all&dicts=all&highlight=on)* - це матеріали, які використовують в процесі *пакування*. То *комплектовання* - це матеріали, які використовують при *комплектуванні*, тобто це і є відповідником російськомовним *комплектующим*. А *комплектувальним* може бути верстат, який призначений для комплектування.